# How do you switch back and forth between Java 1.7 and Java 1.8 on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to have both versions of Java installed on my machine and move to and fro between them. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are moving to Java 8 and still want to run Java 7 the following script might help you.

**Step-by-step guide**
This script that enables you to switch between **Java 1.7** and **Java 1.8**.

Insert the below code block in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` scripts in your home directory.

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
 }
function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
}

#set default jdk version
setjdk 1.7.0_60
```

Once the bash startup scripts are set the following commands can be used to switch between versions in your command line.

```
$ setjdk 1.7
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

To switch back to Java 1.8 and verify your version. Run the following commands.

```
$ setjdk 1.8
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I've used this exact script in my `.bash_profile` for a couple of years and it is glorious. Works as advertised.

Comment: In which scenarios would you need to alternate between the two?

Comment: Just a note, this only affects the java that the command line will see. It doesn't affect the browser plugin. Also it very well may not affect the java that your IDE is using.

Comment: @cricket_007 While working on two different projects it is sometimes necessary to switch back and forth between these two. I have to work on three applications simultaneously out of which two are built on Java 1.7 and uses in house framework which does not work on 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running specific apps on different JDKs then the easiest way is probably to create a script for each app.  You just have to set the appropriate environment variables and then fully path the java executable you want.

The variables you set should be temporary--just for the life of the script.

This isn't a bad idea for all java apps you have anyway rather than typing "Java -jar xxx" all the time.

If you want to run the same app with 2 different versions of java (testing, for instance) then you either need 2 launch scripts for your app or Pritam's solution.